# Different ways to calculate number

Tags: algorithm, racket, integer-partition

I need to write a function that will return the number of ways in which can be n (n is a natural number) written as the sum of natural numbers.
For example: 4 can be written as 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 2+2, 3+1 and 4.
I have written a function that returns the number of all the options, but does not take into account that the possibilities 1 + 1 + 2 and 2 + 1 + 1 (and all similar cases) are equal. So for n=4 it returns 8 instead of 5.
Here is my function:

```
(define (possibilities n)
   (define (loop i)
      (cond [(= i n) 1]
         [(> i n) 0]
         [(+ (possibilities (- n i)) (loop (+ i 1)))]))
     (cond [(< n 1) 0]
        [#t (loop 1)]))
```

Could you please help me with fixing my function, so it will work the way it should be. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with how you're using `cond`. You should use `else` for the last condition, not `#t` and definitely not an expression without a condition as you did in the 5th line of your function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known function, it's called the [partition function P](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), its possible values are referenced as [A000041](http://oeis.org/A000041) in the on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences.

One simple solution (not the fastest!) would be to use this helper function, which denotes the number of ways of writing `n` as a sum of exactly `k` terms:

```
(define (p n k)
  (cond ((> k n) 0)
        ((= k 0) 0)
        ((= k n) 1)
        (else 
         (+ (p (sub1 n) (sub1 k))
            (p (- n k) k)))))
```

Then we just have to add the possible results, being careful with the edge cases:

```
(define (possibilities n)
  (cond ((negative? n) 0)
        ((zero? n) 1)
        (else
         (for/sum ([i (in-range (add1 n))])
           (p n i)))))
```

For example:

```
(map possibilities (range 11))
=> '(1 1 2 3 5 7 11 15 22 30 42)
```